# Distribuited Transactions between COM+ and API Framework 4.6

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, com+, msdtc

how are you doing?  ;)

Can you help me out with this situation? :

We currently have a COM+ Component with DTC (Distributed Transactions)
and I need to migrate the transaction to a API .net (Framework 4.6)  using this transaction to processes returning it back to COM+ to commmit/abort the transaction.

However, I was trying to pass it  in the header as a parameter which is a guid generated from "mCTX.ContextInfo.GetActivityId" to use as a transaction into API (Framework 4.6) . But then the function needs a BASE64 token to validate de GetTransactionFromTransmitterPropagationToken function. Obviosly, to encode to base64 haven't work out to make the function regonize it as an function dtc.  Any ideas how to make it operational?

I haven't found anything similar to study and apply, it's been a big challenge.

**COM+ (Transaction Created)**

> ```
> Private mCTX               As ObjectContext
>
> Set mCTX = GetObjectContext()
> idChaveLog = mCTX.ContextInfo.GetActivityId
>
>
> If Not mCTX Is Nothing Then mCTX.SetComplete
>
> On Error:
>  If Not mCTX Is Nothing Then mCTX.SetAbort
> ```

```
Example Guid Generated in idChaveLog: {38B5C47B-9E50-4AF5-9CB4-F5E6472B9FEB}
```

**API .net (Framework 4.6) (Filter used to get TokenID to propagation of the transaction generated on COM+ (GUID)**

```
public class EnlistToDistributedTransactionActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        private const string TransactionId = "TransactionToken";

        /// <summary>
        /// Retrieve a transaction propagation token, create a transaction scope and promote the current transaction to a distributed transaction.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="actionContext">The action context.</param>
        public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            if (actionContext.Request.Headers.Contains(TransactionId))
            {
                var values = actionContext.Request.Headers.GetValues(TransactionId);
                if (values != null && values.Any())
                {
                    byte[] transactionToken = Convert.FromBase64String(values.FirstOrDefault());
                    var transaction = TransactionInterop.GetTransactionFromTransmitterPropagationToken(transactionToken);
                    var transactionScope = new TransactionScope(transaction);

                    actionContext.Request.Properties.Add(TransactionId, transactionScope);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: `migrate the transaction to a API .net` what do you mean? There are no COM+ services in web apps. Enterprise Services all but disappeared since 2008 when they were replaced by WCF. While there are transaction protocols for SOAP/WCF (WS-Transactions), distributed transactions in general are cumbersome and so never became popular - what happens if the network fails when the ACK is sent? Do you use *three* phase commit? Four? Where do you stop?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? What you posted looks like VB6 code from around 2001. It's 2022 now and distributed applications work in *completely* different ways. COM+ is legacy technology, eventually replaced by AppFabric. And even that was replaced by AppFabric, which went out of support in 2007, replaced by ServiceFabric.

Comment: Hello, @PanagiotisKanavos.  Sorry for the wrong term, my intencion is to integrate the distribuited transaction which has started in the COM+ ( develop in Visual Basic 6) in the api ( develop in c# Framework 4.6).  What I have in mind is make a function in the api to regonize this transaction so the process that occur in the api method could acept and return the status to commit ou abort the transaction back to the COM+

Comment: It's not about terms. I'm saying that not only COM+ is a very old legacy API, distributed transactions in web services were abandoned over a decade ago. That's why they aren't supported by any REST platform. Distributed transactions are a completely artificial concept too - no business works that way. This is explained in [Starbucks doesn't use two-phase commit](https://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/ramblings/18_starbucks.html) That article was written in 2004

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

1. In Windows search and type: "dcomcnfg" to bring up Component Services
2. In the center pane, double click Computers, My Computer, then open the Distributed Transaction Coordinator folder
3. Right click on Local DTC, and choose properties
4. On the Security tab, under Security Settings, check the boxes for
5. Network DTC Access and Enable XA Transactions
6. Click OK to save changes

Comment: What does this have to do with .NET Framework 4.6? The question doesn't ask how to enable distributed transactions. It asks how to use them in .NET Framework 4.6, in an ASP.NET Web API application, which was never built to support such things